# Printing child node using xml

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Here is an api xml i am working with:

```
<response>
    <request>polaris</request>
    <status>0</status>
    <verbiage>OK</verbiage>
    <object id="S251">
        <type id="1">Star</type>
        <name>α UMi</name>
        <catId>α UMi</catId>
        <constellation id="84">Ursa Minor</constellation>
        <ra unit="hour">2.5301944</ra>
        <de unit="degree">89.264167</de>
        <mag>2.02</mag>
    </object>
    <object id="S251">
        <type id="1">Star</type>
        <name>α UMi</name>
        <catId>α UMi</catId>
        <constellation id="84">Ursa Minor</constellation>
        <ra unit="hour">2.5301944</ra>
        <de unit="degree">89.264167</de>
        <mag>2.02</mag>
    </object>
</response>
```

Here is my current code:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   tree = ET.parse('StarGaze.xml')
   root = tree.getroot()
   callevent=root.find('polaris')

   Moc1=callevent.find('polaris')


   for node in Moc1.getiterator():
       if node.tag=='constellation id':
           print node.tag, node.attrib, node.text'
```

I want to be able to print defined children. For example:

constellation id=

ra unit=

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the `object` nodes and locate the `constellation` and `ra` nodes using `findall()` and `find()` methods and `.attrib` attribute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('StarGaze.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for obj in root.findall("object"):
    constellation = obj.find("constellation")
    ra = obj.find("ra")

    print(constellation.attrib["id"], constellation.text, ra.attrib["unit"], ra.text)
```

Would print:

```
84 Ursa Minor hour 2.5301944
84 Ursa Minor hour 2.5301944
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This is running on my raspberry pi. The StarGaze.xml is located in the same folder as the .py code above. I can now run the code without error however, I do not get any printed response?

Comment: @Milesy okay, is the XML that you've posted in the question the same as in the file? Thanks.

Comment: @alexce - yes, exactly the same.

Comment: @Milesy interesting, with exactly this XML inside `Stargaze.xml` and the exactly posted code in the question I'm getting two lines printed on both 2.7 and 3.6 Pythons..

Comment: @alexce - apologies. It was not the same, my file was completely different. The code works perfectly. Thank you.